# How can I avoid dynamic dispatch?

Tags: rust

I have the following trait:

```
struct ArtistInfo {
    // some fields
}

pub trait Fetcher {
    fn fetch(&self, artist: String) -> ArtistInfo;
}
```

I want to have several different fetchers that I can use under different circumstances. My first instinct is to reach for a map and use trait objects like so:

```
type MusicService = String;
let fetchers: HashMap<MusicService, Box<dyn Fetcher>> = HashMap::new();
```

This will allow me to make the set of available music services configurable at run time.

This will result in dynamic dispatch for each of my `Fetcher`s. I'd hazard to guess that this kind of duck typing is a very Object-Oriented way of approaching the problem at hand. Is there potentially a different approach that would avoid the dynamic dispatching?

Comment: What's the method that's being dynamically dispatched? `Fetcher::fetch`? I'm surprised that Rust doesn't automatcally static-dispatch an `impl`'d function, but I'm also not too familiar with the nuances of static vs dynamic dispatch in Rust.

Comment: `fetch` is what would be dynamically dispatched. You can read more about it here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html

Comment: Before avoiding dynamic dispatch, make sure it's not a case of premature optimization. dynamic dispatch HAS overhead, that overhead is often negligible. https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/7v4kfj/impl_trait_vs_boxtrait_or_how_i_learned_to_stop

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know in advance all the types of `Fetcher`s that you'll be using, you can define an `enum` containing a variant for each type.

```
pub enum AnyFetcher {
    Fetcher1(Fetcher1),
    Fetcher2(Fetcher2),
    Fetcher3(Fetcher3),
//  ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
//      |        |
//      |      name of a struct/enum that implements `Fetcher`
//      |
//    name of the enum variant
}
```

Then, instead of using `Box<Fetcher>`, you can use `AnyFetcher`. You'll have to `match` on the enum to do the dispatching yourself, but you'll be dispatching to statically known methods, so this has the benefit that the CPU will be able to see the destination of the function call (contrarily to a true dynamic call).

```
// AnyFetcher doesn't necessarily have to implement Fetcher.
impl Fetcher for AnyFetcher {
    fn fetch(&self, artist: String) -> ArtistInfo {
        match *self {
            AnyFetcher::Fetcher1(ref fetcher) => fetcher.fetch(artist),
            AnyFetcher::Fetcher2(ref fetcher) => fetcher.fetch(artist),
            AnyFetcher::Fetcher3(ref fetcher) => fetcher.fetch(artist),
//                                   ^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                      |                  |
//                                      |        these are static calls...
//                                      |
//              ...because each fetcher variable has a distinct type,
//              which is the type of a concrete Fetcher implementation
        }
    }
}
```

If you're going with this approach, you may realize that the `Fetcher` trait doesn't actually serve a purpose at this point; `fetch` could just as well be an inherent method on each fetcher type.

Comment: I guess the advantage of a boxed trait is that someone who uses this library, could extend the `Fetcher` trait for their own struct, while it would be harder to add another enum variant (of that struct implementing a `fetcher()` method directly) to `AnyFetcher` (other than (re)defining one's own `AnyFetcher` enum)?

Comment: Enum was definitely a solution I was considering. Although as @Evert pointed out that makes it hard to write an extensible library (indeed, the ability to add new types easily is the exact argument the Rust book makes for using Trait Objects).

I think the last point about not needing a `Fetcher` trait might be the real realization here. Let me think about this a little more...

Comment: @Evert If you have a mix of known and unknown implementations, you can add a variant holding a `Box<Fetcher>` to the enum to handle the unknown implementations. If you *only* have unknown implementations (or the known implementations are not important enough to warrant their own enum variant), then you can't avoid dynamic dispatch (unless you take an extreme approach such as dynamic code generation).

Comment: Stating the point more bluntly: if you have *dynamic* implementations of code, you cannot avoid *dynamic* dispatch. It's all about what requirements you have for your code.

Comment: Oooo. "have a catch all enum that uses dynamic dispatch for the ones you don't know about, and concrete ones for the rest" a really interesting approach.

Comment: @shepmaster I think has the ultimate point here. My code seems to be dynamic, perhaps I should just not fight that.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Francis Gagné's answer: It is possible to reduce to amount of boilerplate required for implementing static dispatch by using macros. For instance, there is the [enum dispatch](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) crate which simplifies the example to:

```rust
// Add macro to the trait definition
#[enum_dispatch(AnyFechter)]
pub trait Fetcher {
    fn fetch(&self, artist: String) -> ArtistInfo;
}

// Add a wrapper enum
#[enum_dispatch]
pub enum AnyFetcher {
    Fetcher1,
    Fetcher2,
    Fetcher3,
}
```

For a given `fetcher: AnyFetcher` it is now possible to call `fetcher.fetch(...)` without dynamic dispatch as if one would have written out the dispatching manually using `match`.

Note that

- it requires to adapt the trait definition, and couple it to the wrapping enum.
- the wrapping enum doesn't require to write out the new-type `Fetcher1(Fetcher1)` (by default the enum branches get the same name as the underlying type, but they can be specified manually if custom names are needed).
- in contrast to writing out the `match` manually, the trait has not lost its purpose, and is in fact needed -- it basically serves as the common denominator for the static dispatch code generation.